# How to use find to make copies of file with prefix in CSH?

Tags: linux, unix, copy, find, csh

I am trying to make copies of certain file and let them have a prefix.
in order to do it I thought of using `find`. for our use, let's call them kuku files and I want them to have a "foo" prefix:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "kuku*" -exec cp '{}' foo_'{}' \;
```

but it doesn't work because the find always starts the results with ./ so i get a lot of error messages saying "cp: cannot create regular file `foo_./kuku...`: No such file or directory".

the problem is solvable by using foreach f (`ls`) and than using grep and the status var, but it is cumbersome and I want to learn a better solution (and improve my knowledge of the find command along the way...).

**update** foreach solution (which I don't like and want your help in finding a replacement):

```
foreach f (`ls`)
  echo $f | grep -lq kuku
  if (! $status) then
    cp $f foo_$f
  endif
end
```

but this is UGLY! **(end of update)**

as the header says, I'm using csh - not because I love it, just because that's what we use at work...

**update**
trying to use `basename` as a solution, because `find -exec basename '{}' \;` removes the ./ prefix, but i failed using the basename inside the find with backticks (`), meaning that

```
find -name "kuku*" -exec cp '{}' foo_`basename '{}` \;
```

simply doesn't work.

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17433020/1983854

Comment: I can't find the difference between the link you gave me and the solution I suggested and said is too cumbersome and unwanted. Thanks for the link anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.. I have tested in my linux box

```
find . -name "kuku*" -exec sh -c 'cp {} foo_`basename {}`' \;
```

Comment: yep, that works! was so close with the exec though :( . Thanks Mari.